# Detetar outliers em dados agrupados

Tags: r

Estou a trabalhar com dados em painel e necessitava identificar os potenciais outliers em cada grupo, exemplo:

```
df <- data.frame(
    ID_group = c("1","1","2","1","3","2","2","3"),
    Case = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"),
    Var_X = c("1","2","1","2","3","5","6","10"),
    Var_Y = c("10,02","5","7","5,5","2,5","7","600,23","2,8"))
```

Gostaria de conseguir identificar possíveis outlier existentes na variável **Var_X** em cada **ID_group** criando uma coluna onde seja marcado se o caso identificado em **Case** é considerado um outlier na **var_X** e no **ID_group** ao qual pertence.

Comment: Qual o método de detecção que utilizará?

Comment: vou usar z-score

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Identificar *outliers*

Existem vários procedimentos para identificar *outliers*, a escolha do método e dos critérios de corte dependem dos seus dados e o objetivo da análise. Os mais usados são intervalo interquartil (IQR) e *z-score*.

### *z-score*

Faz-se a normatização por média e desvio e considera-se *outliers* valores acima de *x* vezes o desvio padrão (usualmente 3):

```
is.outlier <- function(x, sd = 3) abs(scale(x)) > sd
```

### IQR

Calcula-se a diferença entre o 1º e 3º quartis (25% e 75%) e multiplica-se por um coeficiente (usualmente 1,5). Considera-se *outliers* valores abaixo ou acima dessa distância dos interquartis:

```
is.outlier <- function(x, coef = 1.5, ...) {
  q <- quantile(x, c(.25, .75), na.rm = TRUE, ...)
  iqr <- diff(q)
  x < q[1] - coef*iqr | x > q[2] + coef*iqr
}
```

Alternativamente, pode usar a função `boxplot.stats` (usada internamente pela `boxplot`):

```
is.outlier <- function(x) x %in% boxplot.stats(x)$out
```

## Identificar por grupo

Criei um exemplo mais indicativo e vou usar a última função de exemplo (identificar por *z-score* só é adequado para *n* alto).

```
df <- data.frame(
  grupo = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 5),
  Y = c(1:4, 100:104, 1000))
```

### Com R base

Usando `split` e `apply`. Apenas garanta primeiro que os dados estão ordenados por grupo, para o resultado ser anexado corretamente.

```
df <- df[order(df$grupo), ]
df$outlier <- unlist(lapply(split(df$Y, df$grupo), is.outlier))

df
#>    grupo    Y outlier
#> 1      A    1   FALSE
#> 2      A    2   FALSE
#> 3      A    3   FALSE
#> 4      A    4   FALSE
#> 5      A  100    TRUE
#> 6      B  101   FALSE
#> 7      B  102   FALSE
#> 8      B  103   FALSE
#> 9      B  104   FALSE
#> 10     B 1000    TRUE
```

### Com dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

df %<>% group_by(grupo) %>% mutate(outlier = is.outlier(Y))
```

### Com data.table

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[, outlier := is.outlier(Y), grupo]
```

Comment: Obg pela resposta, muito didatica. Ia usar z-score mas, como tenho grupos com 5 a 10 observações, talvez tenha de usar IQR

Answer (score 0):

Eu peguei seu exemplo, primeiro criei um *data.frame*, transformando as variáveis em numérico.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  id_group = c("1","1","2","1","3","2","2","3"),
  Case = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"),
  var_x = c("1","2","1","2","3","5","6","10"),
  var_y = c("10.02","5","7","5.5","2.5","7","600.23","2.8")
  ) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("var_"), as.numeric))
```

Depois eu agrupei pela variável **id_group** e apliquei a função *mutate* para criar uma nova variável (**out_var_x**) que indica o *outlier*, no caso usei uma condição qualquer, sendo ela se o valor de **var_x** for maior que o quantil 90% do seu grupo, porém pode adicionar outro critério.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id_group) %>% 
  mutate(out_var_x = if_else(var_x > quantile(var_x,.9),TRUE,FALSE))

# A tibble: 8 x 5
# Groups:   ID_group [3]
  id_group case  var_x var_y out_var_x
  <chr>    <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>    
1 1        A         1  10.0 FALSE    
2 1        B         2   5   FALSE    
3 2        C         1   7   FALSE    
4 1        D         2   5.5 FALSE    
5 3        E         3   2.5 FALSE    
6 2        F         5   7   FALSE    
7 2        G         6 600.  TRUE     
8 3        H        10   2.8 TRUE
```

Comment: Estar acima ou abaixo de um quantil não é critério para ser considerado *outlier*

Comment: Carlos, o exemplo do quantil foi só um demonstrativo de como fazer no R, o critério em si é arbitrário. Existem várias técnicas de como identificar *outliers*, inclusive isso vai depender muito do fenômeno e do objetivo. Tanto que comento acima que usei uma condição qualquer só para exemplificar a lógica de aplicação.